# блок продолжает ехать)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

блок продолжает ехать но должен заползать назад. должно получиться меню.
и как сделать что бы при клике на пустоту блок закрывался?
и фон затемнялся)

```js
$('#pollSlider-button').click(function() {
 if($(this).css("margin-left") == "70%")
 {
  $('.pollSlider').animate({"margin-left": '-=70%'});
  $('#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-left": '-=70%'});
 }
 else
 {
     $('.pollSlider').animate({"margin-left": '+=70%'});
  $('#pollSlider-button').animate({"margin-left": '+=70%'});
    }
});
```

```css
.pollSlider{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    width:70%;
    left:0px;
    margin-left: -70%;
}
#pollSlider-button{
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    left:0px;
    background:green;
    top:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pollSlider"></div>
<div id="pollSlider-button"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(this).css("margin-left")` - не вернет значение в процентах, а вернёт в пикселях. А вообще, я бы сделал чуть проще:

```js
var pollSlider = $('.pollSlider');
$('#pollSlider-button').click(function() {
  pollSlider.toggleClass('slide-left');
});
```

```css
.pollSlider {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  width: 70%;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: -70%;
  -webkit-transition: margin-left .5s linear;
  transition: margin-left .5s linear;
}
#pollSlider-button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 0;
  margin-right: -100px;
  background: green;
  top: 100px;
}
.slide-left {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pollSlider">
  <div id="pollSlider-button"></div>
</div>
```